# How strcut blk_plug works with multi thread?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

The Linux source code [remark](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/blkdev.h#L1319) say `blk_plug` is a per-task list and there is no any lock in the `strcut`:

```
/*
 * blk_plug permits building a queue of related requests by holding the I/O
 * fragments for a short period. This allows merging of sequential requests
 * into single larger request. As the requests are moved from a per-task list to
 * the device's request_queue in a batch, this results in improved scalability
 * as the lock contention for request_queue lock is reduced.
 *
 * It is ok not to disable preemption when adding the request to the plug list
 * or when attempting a merge, because blk_schedule_flush_list() will only flush
 * the plug list when the task sleeps by itself. For details, please see
 * schedule() where blk_schedule_flush_plug() is called.
 */
struct blk_plug {
  struct list_head list; 
  struct list_head mq_list; 
  struct list_head cb_list; 
}
```

How `struct blk_plug` keep its safe under multi thread process?

Comment: Each process(thread) access only that `blk_plug` instance, which is belongs to it. So no concurrent access is possible. (This is similar to access local variables, declared in the function body).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found that struct blk_plug declared in a function(such as do_blockdev_direct_IO) might pointed by variable plug in struct task_struct, thus I think the blk_plug might be used by many threads. It really confused me.

Comment: Yes, pointer to `blk_plug` instance is stored in the `current` (per-thread instance of type `struct task_struct`). While other threads technically can access it, they actually do not do that: I have found only accesses through the `current` pointer. So each process accesses only its own `blk_plug` instance, as I have said in my previous comment.

Comment: Appreciating your explanation.